# Vertically aligning the button with the TextField in React Material-UI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using the Material-UI library for React.
I am trying to make a simple form that looks like:

[image]

However, I can't figure out how to align the button with the `TextField`.
I tried changing the `margin-top` but it increases the margin of the entire wrapper.
Below is the code sandbox for it.

Any tips on getting this fixed?

https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-y5eg7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 2):

In your styles.css file you can add `{position: relative; top: 10px}` to the small-button className then adjust the top value until you are happy with the position alternatively you might be able to wrap the row in a div and use `{display:flex; flex-direction:row; justify-content:center;}` to align them all.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace this line

```js
<div className="input-text-wrapper">
```

with

```js
<div className="input-text-wrapper" style={{display:"flex", alignItems:"center"}} >
```

AND remove margin-bottom from your style.css

```css
.input-text-wrapper-small {
  width: 30%;
  /*margin-bottom: 1.2em;*/
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the below styles in styles.css

```
.horizontal-form { /* This is newly added style */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.input-text-wrapper {
  /* margin-bottom: 1.2em; */ /* comment these styles */ 
}

.input-text-wrapper-small {
  width: 33%;
  /* margin-bottom: 1.2em; */
  display: inline-block;
}

.small-button {
  width: 10%;
  /* display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center; */
}
```

jsx

Remove the small-button div from inside the input-text-wrapper div and Then Enclose the input-text-wrapper div and small-button div inside a newly created horizontal-form div

```
...
</Typography>
<div className="horizontal-form">
   <div className="input-text-wrapper">
      <div className="input-text-wrapper-small">
         ...
      </div>
      <div className="input-text-wrapper-small">
         ...
      </div>
      <div className="input-text-wrapper-small">
         ...
      </div>
   </div>
   <div className="small-button">
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
      Add
      </Button>
   </div>
</div>
</CardContent>
....
```